# Unable to boot Windows after installing Fedora

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Fedora 20 alongside Windows 8.1, now I am able to get into Fedora but my Windows is unable to boot.

On startup it shows list of installed OSes in which the last option is "Windows Boot Loader", but when I choose this option it shows an error.

Comment: Can you specify what the error is about? Preferably copy/paste it here, or post a photo if the it is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

We would like more information on that. Have you ever successfully booted Windows 8 after installing fedora? We must be certain that nothing windows-wise was accidentally deleted. Furthermore, [these](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/41984/uefi-dual-boot-windows-81-and-fedora-20/) [five](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/23442/cant-boot-windows7-after-installing-fedora18/) [links](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/9766/how-could-i-dual-boot-fedora-18-and-windows-8-on-secure-boot-mode/) [might](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/39886/after-fedora20-install-dual-boot-neither-windows-8-or-fedora-20-wont-start/) be [helpful](http://amidstsky.com/tech/install-ubuntu-or-fedora-in-dual-boot-with-windows-8-1-uefi/).